# Gem tests can't find route using url_for

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, routes, rubygems, rspec2, rspec-rails

I think the dummy app in which my gem tests are meant to run is not set up properly, because when I call `url_for` on a Gadget instance (a stub model from the dummy app) within the gem's helper, I get

```
undefined method `gadgets_path' for #<#<Class:0x007fe274bc1228>:0x007fe273d45eb0>
```

**Background:** I forked a gem and made some significant changes. ([Here's the fork](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails).) Now I'm trying to make the rspec tests work so I can verify my updates going forward.

The tests are set up like a Rails engine, with a dummy app within the `spec` directory. That app has one model (`Gadget`) with an appropriate controller and a resource declared in the `spec/dummy/environment/routes.rb` file:

```
Dummy::Application.routes.draw do
  resources :gadgets
end
```

The `spec/spec_helper.rb` file looks like this:

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"

require File.expand_path("../dummy/config/environment", __FILE__)
require 'rspec/rails'

require 'rspec/autorun'

RSpec.configure do |config|
  config.mock_framework = :rspec
  config.fixture_path = "#{::Rails.root}/spec/fixtures"
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
  config.infer_base_class_for_anonymous_controllers = false
  config.order = "random"

  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
end
```

(You can actually see the full test setup in [the project's github repo](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails). I actually opened [an issue](https://github.com/pjmorse/jeditable-wysiwyg-rails/issues/6) for this a week or so ago, but only now am I getting around to trying to resolve it.)

The one test which isn't pending creates a Gadget instance, then calls the helper with that as an argument. When the helper tries `url_for(@gadget)`, it triggers the above error.

What's wrong here?

ETA Dec 04: Updated with the current `spec_helper.rb`.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

**Update**

put this inside your spec_helper.rb - at least this works for me  ( i cloned your repo )

```
ActionView::TestCase::TestController.instance_eval do
  helper Rails.application.routes.url_helpers#, (append other helpers you need)
end
ActionView::TestCase::TestController.class_eval do
  def _routes
    Rails.application.routes
  end
end
```

The real problem was that `TestController` was subclassed from `ActionController::Base` **before** `ActionController::Base` is extended with the route helper methods.
So you need to inject it back into the `TestController`. Furthermore AbstractController::UrlFor requires `_routes` to be implemented.

---

In order to use the routing helpers you should insert

```
Rspec.configure do |config|
  config.include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  ...
end
```

in your spec_helper.rb which makes all `something_path` methods available.
Another way **around the real issue** would be to stub out the helper like so:

```
helper.stub!(:url_for).and_return("/path")
```

Comment: This looks promising, and when I go into the dummy application and use the Rails console I can poke that object and get the paths back. However, it doesn't allow the tests to run. I've updated the `spec_helper.rb` code above with your suggestion. (It's also updated on Github.)

Comment: You're absolutely right about "the real issue," and that by itself solves the problem.

Comment: Thank you! This fixed my spec that was throwing this error: `Failure/Error: helper.url_for(subdomain: 'app', controller: 'dashboard', action: 'index').should eq 'http://app.example.com/'
RuntimeError: In order to use #url_for, you must include routing helpers explicitly. For instance, include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers`

Answer (score 1):

While that is quite a bit of source code to take in, it seems to me that you are calling `editable_field` which in turn calls `url_for`. However `url_for` will only work in the context of a controller, whereas you are calling it simply in the middle of a spec.

So perhaps either stubbing this method out or doing an integration test would be a suitable workaround.

Comment: `editable_field` is a helper method. `url_for` does in fact work perfectly well in the helper; it's in the testing context that it isn't working. Stubbing `editable_field` is not a suitable workaround because it is the method I'm trying to test.

Comment: If you pull up the rails console and do `editable_field` will it work? I don't think it would, since it needs to be in the context of a request, which sets up the environment for `url_for` to work in. So I was suggesting to stub `url_for` rather than `editable_field`.

Comment: You're right, it doesn't work in the console. That's three votes for stubbing `url_for`, now, and that makes a lot of sense.

Comment: Also, thanks for pointing out the request context and how it sets up the environment for `url_for`. I hadn't realized that, although of course it makes perfect sense now that I do know.